# Using TPU without GCS

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, tpu

Is there a way to use TPU in Colab/Kaggle notebook **without** hosting your dataset on a GCS bucket? Does Google/Kaggle provide that functionality yet?

P.S.: I am using TensorFlow v2.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, it seems impossible. However, you can connect to an external hub to retrieve the necessary data for training.

Dagshub is already doing that.

https://dagshub.com/

You can create a private repository and create a workflow.

https://dagshub.com/martin-fabbri/tpu-workflow/src/0ebfac90c65098150d1fe3b9b3dcf14e45f372cf

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know to provide additional information.